# Is there a way to inspect native actions on IOS device, such as popup elements

Tags: ios, appium, devtools, inspector

I need a tool such as "uiautomatorviewer" for android to inspect native ios elements on IOS real device (such as ios warning popups).
I have to get the "ID" of popup window elements like (Ok and Cancel) buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Debug Hierarchy feature in Xcode:

[image]

Should give you all the info you need (unless you're trying to do something nefarious).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that wont work with the ios system windows like system popup or if you want to select a default application window such as the below image:

![ios popup image](https://ibb.co/mfKL0k)

Comment: OK - curious though... why are you trying to get IDs of those elements?

Comment: I need a unique selector to click on the option like "gmail" option in the image in my previous comment.

Comment: Hmmm... to "make the selection with the user being able to prevent it?" Might have trouble getting that approved...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Appium iOS Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector):

- download this repository
- stop application during running test (e.g. set breakpoint in debug mode)
- open "iOS Inspector.html" file in browser
  And you will see app xml structure.